# Null value passed with select2 field type

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack, eloquent-relationship

My Product model has a `code` foreign key which points to a Code model, which also has a `code` coulmn but as a primary key. In the Create view of Product's CRUD, I created a dropdown field that allows me to choose from all the already existing Codes using the Select2 field type.

```
[
    'label'     => 'Code',
    'type'      => 'select2',
    'name'      => 'code',             // the foreign key
    'entity'    => 'productCode',      // the relationship's method
    'model'     => 'App\Models\Code', 
    'attribute' => 'code',             // attribute that is shown in the dropdown
]
```

The codes are shown correctly in the dropdown, but when I save the new product the code field is stored in the request as a null value. Anyone knows what the issue could be? Or if I'm getting some of this wrong?

This is the relationship in the Product model:

```
public function productCode() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Code', 'code', 'code');
}
```

Comment: In your `App\Models\Code` model, is `code` the primary key of that table?, if so, do you have a property like `protected $primaryKey = 'code';` on that model? If not, could you try adding one and

Comment: If the above guesses are in line with your usage and `code` is an alpha-numeric value, you may also need to add `protected $keyType = 'string';` to your model.

Comment: `code` is a 9 char numeric string and yes, it's Code's primary key

Comment: And the model does already specify that with the properties above, correct?

Comment: Ok wow, I added the two lines of code you said and now it works, the code is correctly stored in the request, I didn't have a clue you had to specify the primary key and its type also in the model

Comment: Thank you so much Wesley! You saved day

Comment: Anytime, happy to help. Yeah, `primaryKey` is only needed if your primary key is not the typical "id" and `keyType ` is only needed if that primary key is not an integer column, This has bitten me enough times to recognize it pretty quickly now ;)

Comment: Well that's very good to know, I think it will come in handy many many times!

Comment: added as an answer to help others in the future. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

A `primaryKey` property is required on a model when your primary key is not the typical "id" column, and `keyType` property is required  if that primary key is not an integer column:

Adding the below to your `App\Models\Code` model should fix the problem:

```
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var  string
 */
 protected $primaryKey = 'code';


/**
 * The "type" of the primary key
 *
 * @var  string
 */
protected $keyType = 'string';
```